# Read Authors@R field from DESCRIPTION of R package as vector

Tags: r, package, metadata, r-package

How can I read `Authors@R` field from `DESCRIPTION` file as vector?

```
> packageDescription("dplyr")$`Authors@R`
[1] "\n    c(person(given = \"Hadley\",\n             family = \"Wickham\",\n             role = c(\"aut\", \"cre\"),\n             email = \"hadley@rstudio.com\",\n             comment = c(ORCID = \"0000-0003-4757-117X\")),\n      person(given = \"Romain\",\n             family = \"François\",\n             role = \"aut\",\n             comment = c(ORCID = \"0000-0002-2444-4226\")),\n      person(given = \"Lionel\",\n             family = \"Henry\",\n             role = \"aut\"),\n      person(given = \"Kirill\",\n             family = \"Müller\",\n             role = \"aut\",\n             comment = c(ORCID = \"0000-0002-1416-3412\")),\n      person(given = \"RStudio\",\n             role = c(\"cph\", \"fnd\")))"
```

Comment: There is a private, un-exported function that does the reading of this field when building the documentation `utils:::.read_authors_at_R_field( packageDescription("dplyr")$`Authors@R`)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may wrap with `eval(parse` as it returns a string

```
eval(parse(text = packageDescription("dplyr")$`Authors@R`))
```

i.e. if we check with `cat`

```
cat(packageDescription("dplyr")$`Authors@R`)

    c(person(given = "Hadley",
             family = "Wickham",
             role = c("aut", "cre"),
             email = "hadley@rstudio.com",
             comment = c(ORCID = "0000-0003-4757-117X")),
      person(given = "Romain",
             family = "François",
             role = "aut",
             comment = c(ORCID = "0000-0002-2444-4226")),
      person(given = "Lionel",
             family = "Henry",
             role = "aut"),
      person(given = "Kirill",
             family = "Müller",
             role = "aut",
             comment = c(ORCID = "0000-0002-1416-3412")),
      person(given = "RStudio",
             role = c("cph", "fnd")))
```

Comment: Thanks! I also found another way: `packageDescription("OneSupplyReconciliation", fields = "Authors@R") %>% str2lang() %>% eval() `.